# Advice on dual booting windows+ ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, grub

Last time I tried to dual boot windows and ubuntu I lost Grub, and after a couple mistakes had to reinstall. I still want windows, but I don't want to get burned again. I've been doing some research and saw that I probably would want to disable fast boot and mark windows boot manager as inactive. Does this sound right, or should I do something else? my pc isn't powerful enough to run windows in a vm except for very mild workloads. Thanks.
NOTE: ubuntu is already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to install Windows after installing Ubuntu. It is easier to do the opposite: install Windows then install Ubuntu. Indeed the installation of Windows replaces GRUB by Windows Boot Loader.

You must reinstall GRUB in order to use Ubuntu. A simple way to do this is to use a Live version of Ubuntu. Once Live Ubuntu has been loaded, open a terminal and install the [boot repair utility](https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair) with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Then start the utility with the `boot-repair` command or simply from the application menu and select the `Recommended repair`.

[image: Boot repair utility screenshot from (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)]

When repair is finished you should be able to boot on Ubuntu after a reboot. For more information have a look at this [article in the Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). The screenshot comes from this article.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, something else I had to do is run this In the Windows admin command prompt:    **bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi** .Possibly put this in your answer to help future people? also, maybe add to only select the first Windows option or it might reset the bootloader.